# Unique Distinct List Adds Extra '0' Lines

Tags: excel

I'm currently working on making an Excel tab that consolidates two different columns of data into a unique list. This has been covered elsewhere; my formula comes from "[Extract a unique distinct list from two columns...](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/06/16/extract-an-unique-distinct-list-from-two-columns-using-excel-2007-array-formula/)"

The formula itself, to not reiterate the approach but at least give enough detail here, is as follows:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(List1, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C$1:C1,List1), 0)), INDEX(List2, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C$1:C1,List2), 0))), "")
```

*Note that the above formula is using named range that is inclusive of only the values, not the headers, and no additional cells with whitespace.*

The problem I'm encountering is that if my list is too *short*, an extra entry with '0' is created at the end of the distinct list. Here's an example:

```
Col1:    Col2:    Unique:
-------  -----    -------
A        D        A
B                 B
C                 C
                  D
                  0
```

The trend I've found is that if *either* column has less than three entries, then the '0' will be present in the resulting unique list. If, however, both lists has at least 3 items, no '0' entry will be present:

```
Col1:    Col2:    Unique:
-------  -----    -------
A        D        A
B        E        B
C        F        C
                  D
                  E
                  F
```

**In short**, I'm hoping someone can help me fix my formula to no longer require at least three entries in each column, or at least find a way to exclude the '0' entry.

Thanks!!!

Comment: If you want a quick, superficial, fix, you can edit the cells' format to be "Custom", then enter this ` 0;-0;;@`.  That should hide the 0s that results from `Index()`.  Note though this doesn't fix the formula really, but rather cosmetically hides the resulting zeroes.  Edit: Eh, actually I don't know if this is what you want - you don't want to hide the zero, correct? That 0 should instead be an "E"?

Comment: As an aside, I realize I can brute force this with the following:

`=IF(IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(List1, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C$1:C1,List1), 0)), INDEX(List2, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C$1:C1,List2), 0))), "")=0, "", IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(List1, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C$1:C1,List1), 0)), INDEX(List2, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C$1:C1,List2), 0))), ""))`

Comment: @BruceWayne That won't help me, as I'm using the distinct result list as a source for another formula later. I want the '0' to come back as an empty record entirely.